# Moving Firefox profiles from snap version to deb version under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, firefox, snap, deb

I ran into a problem converting from Firefox snap to Firefox deb under Ubuntu 18.04.

The Firefox snap is version 72.0.2 and the Firefox deb is version 72.0.1.

The error I’m getting is about using a profile on an older version of Firefox. “Using and older version of Firefox...”

The odd thing is that I was moving 5 profiles, the first three worked, the last two failed with that error.

I made sure Ubuntu was up-to-date suing the Software Updater before starting, shut down all running instances of Firefox, made back up copies of the snap profiles, uninstalled the snap version using Ubuntu Software, installed the deb version using apt-get since it was removed form Ubuntu Software.

Then, as each user. I ran the Firefox Profile manager (firefox -P) to create profiles with the same names as before, then, as each user, copied the backed up snap profiles into the new locations. Then ran the profile managed to test each profile.

The first three profiles worked without a problem, the last two failed with the “older version” error. The first three belong to two users and the last two to on user.

Is there something I can do now to get the last two profiles to work with the deb version.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked if firework was running on the background?

Comment: I don’t know what firework is and a quick search didn't turn up anything, but if you meant Firefox then, yes I checked to make sure it was shut down for the problem user before copying the profiles.